Meaning of curly brackets ({}) when a website (search) fails
I've been unable to use https://search.worldcat.org/ for the past month because every search returns the characters {}
Is there any regular meaning associated to this failure?


That's a function of their own internal code. It could be the server throwing an error, or a bug in the site's code. The only people who know would be their server admins.

Works in Firefox.

Works in Brave for me

{} means empty JSON response most likely, but no clue why you need to know that. Much more useful would be to check the full responses in Chrome Dev Tools - there could be anything useful there. Or ro ask the administration.

Since it works in Firefox and Brave, the problem must be on your end.  I would suggest that you hard refresh on the browser, or delete the cache.
